# How would this code be refactored to use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would this code be refactored to use jQuery?

```
function emleProcessOnLoad(aThis) {
  var result = document.evaluate("//span[@class='emleOnLoad']",
    aThis.document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (var jj=0; jj<result.snapshotLength; jj++){
    eval("var emleThis=result.snapshotItem(jj);" + result.snapshotItem(jj).textContent);
  }
}
```

There appears to be four issues for jQuery to address:

1. Context: `aThis.document`
2. Selection: `//span[@class='emleOnLoad']`
3. Iteration: `for (var jj=0; jj<result.snapshotLength; jj++)`
4. Value: `.textContent`

The code is a fragment from [Emle - Electronic Mathematics Laboratory Equipment](http://emle.sourceforge.net/emle020406/emle_index.html) JavaScript file [emle_lab.js](http://emle.sourceforge.net/emle020406/emle_lab.js).

The `.evaluate()` function grabs all of the `<span>` tags which have class `emleOnLoad`. The resulting text content contains an expression fragment such as:

```
emleHandleInput(emleThis.parentNode.parentNode,"EMLE_CET_PROPER_FRACTION");
```

which is appended to:

```
var emleThis=result.snapshotItem(jj);
```

and then is executed for each item found by the `.evaluate()` function.

Comment: Eval is Evil!  Be very careful when using eval, especially if your source is not trustworthy.

Comment: The current effort is to refactor Emle with jQuery which at this point has reduced LoC by 30%. I have added Eval-Is-Evil blueprint to the Emle project: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/emle/+spec/eval-is-evil

Comment: On the other hand, if the source *is* trusted, there is nothing inherently wrong with eval.

Comment: Moved namespace component of question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572304/what-is-jquery-for-document-createelementns

Answer (score 1):

The main loop can be simplified down to this

```
$("span.emleOnLoad").each(function() {
   var content = $(this).text();
   // do something with content
});
```

but the whole idea needs some rethinking. Store chunks of javascript in spans and eval them at run time -  this is quite weird.

Comment: Yup. extremelu weird, but he said something about it being math stuff, so showing the evaluated part is propably a feature. A dangerous one :)

Comment: There is no advantage to using eval here. It doesn't matter if it's "math stuff".

Comment: Just need to add the context node, `aThis.document`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, but I would replace the switch with this:

```
var lu = (function() {
   var TYPES = { // call it whatever you want
    'xhtml':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    'math': 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML',
    'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  };
  return function luf(aPrefix){
    return TYPES[aPrefix] || '';
  };
})();
```

First, I create an anonymous function and call it so that I can declare local variables, otherwise `TYPES` will end up in (presumably) global scope. Then I create an object (map/hash) that maps the values just like your switch would. Finally, create another anonymous function that looks the prefix up in `TYPES` and defaults to ''.

The rest is pretty messed up.