# What is jQuery for Document.createElementNS()?

Tags: jquery, xml-namespaces

What is jQuery for Document.createElementNS()?

```
function emleGraphicToSvg(aGraphicNode) {
  var lu = function luf(aPrefix){
    switch (aPrefix){
      case 'xhtml': return 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
      case 'math':  return 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML';
      case 'svg':   return 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
      }
    return '';
    };
  var svg = document.evaluate("svg:svg",
    aGraphicNode, lu, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).
    singleNodeValue;
  $(svg).children().remove();
  rect = document.createElementNS(lu('svg'), "rect");
  rect.setAttribute("x", "35");
  rect.setAttribute("y", "25");
  rect.setAttribute("width", "200");
  rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
  rect.setAttribute("class", "emleGraphicOutline");
  svg.appendChild(rect);
  }
```

The code is a simplified fragment from [Emle - Electronic Mathematics Laboratory Equipment](http://emle.sourceforge.net/emle020406/emle_index.html) JavaScript file [emle_lab.js](http://emle.sourceforge.net/emle020406/emle_lab.js).

The Look-Up-Function, `luf()`, maps a complete reference to a shorten name for the namespace in the XPath string and `createElementNS()`. The existing `svg:svg` is located, removed and replaced by a new rectangle.

Comment: I also need to know what does createElementNS() do. Here is my related question in svg-edit: 
http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/issues/detail?id=574

Answer (score 5):

> What is jQuery for Document.createElementNS()?

That would be:

```
$(document.createElementNS('namespace', 'tag'))
```

So in the OP's case:

```
rect = $(document.createElementNS(lu('svg'), 'rect'))
    .addClass('emleGraphicOutline')
    .attr({
        x: 35,
        y: 25,
        width: 200,
        height: 50
    });
```

But not much is really gained by using jQuery for that, of course. In any case, one can always wrap DOM nodes in jQuery with e.g. `$(rect)` after creating `rect` with vanilla JS.

Note that jQuery has other issues with SVG, such as breaking `viewBox` due to [lowercasing attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361971/does-the-attr-in-jquery-force-lowercase), so plain JS must still be used for some attributes.

Answer (score 2):

For SVG, I have used [Keith Wood's jquery.svg](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) for some evaluation type projects.

Comment: The svg is just an example. I assume jquery.svg is not for handling namespaces other than svg. I am looking for how to handle namespaces with Jquery, specifically createElementNS().

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII I haven't found a good way to do this yet, though you can always get work around jquery and use createElementNS() and setAttributeNS() yourself, like this: http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/09/using-svg-elements-with-jquery_6812.html