# Does the attr() in jQuery force lowercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, attr, lowercase

I'm trying to manipulate the svg 'viewBox' attribute which looks something like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" width="100" ...> ... </svg>
```

Using

```
$("svg").attr("viewBox","...");
```

However, this creates a new attribute in the element called "viewbox". Notice the lowercase instead of intended camelCase. Is there another function I should be using?

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11166

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390346/why-is-jquery-auto-lower-casing-attribute-values

Comment: Thanks andres. Tried searching but didn't find that one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to use pure javascript to get the element and set the attribute by using

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
```

and

```
svg.setAttribute("viewBox","...");
```

Answer (score 5):

Per http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2 "XHTML documents must use lower case for all HTML element and attribute names."

So in order to avoid having the attribute convert to lowercase in an XHTML document you need to create the element specifying a namespace using `document.createElementNS()`, like:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 512 512’);
```

If you plan to add a `<use/>` element you also need to specify the namespace while creating the element as well as the `xlink:href` attribute, like:

```js
var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','use');
    use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#your_svg_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery hooks:

```
['preserveAspectRatio', 'viewBox'].forEach(function(k) {
  $.attrHooks[k.toLowerCase()] = {
    set: function(el, value) {
      el.setAttribute(k, value);
      return true;
    },
    get: function(el) {
      return el.getAttribute(k);
    },
  };
});
```

Now jQuery will will use your setter/getters to manipulate those attributes.

**Note** that `el.attr('viewBox', null)` would have failed; your hook setter won't be called. Instead you should use el.removeAttr('viewBox').

Comment: While this method works, it does not prevent the old behavior from occurring. So an element will end up with both `viewbox` and `viewBox` attributes. Not that it won't work, but it isn't as clean as it could be.

Comment: Fixed. The setter should return `true`

Answer (score -2):

you want to make sure you remove the attr if it already exists before manipulating it

```
$("svg").removeAttr("viewBox")
```

and then recreating it

```
$("svg").attr("viewBox","...");
```