# How to prevent AngularJS from making lowercase HTML attributes

Tags: svg, angularjs

I am trying to render some SVG with AngularJS but I can't dynamically change the viewbox of the svg element.

Angular renders a 'viewbox' attribute, but browsers expect a 'viewBox' attribute. So the result is:

```
<svg height="151px" width="1366px" viewBox="{{ mapViewbox }}" viewbox="-183 425 1366 151">
```

How can I get the result I expect:

```
<svg height="151px" width="1366px" viewBox="-183 425 1366 151">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See if this directive works:

```
app.directive('vbox', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('vbox', function(value) {
        element.attr('viewBox', value);
      })
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<svg height="151px" width="1366px" vbox="{{ mapViewbox }}">
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GAitczSyGR7ACrHuPVfx?p=preview).  You'll need to "Inspect element" or "View source" to see the svg tag.

**Update:** If your app includes jQuery, see [Does the attr() in jQuery force lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361971/does-the-attr-in-jquery-force-lowercase)

@Niahoo found that this worked if jQuery is included (he made an edit to this post, but for some reason, other SO moderators rejected it... I liked it though, so here it is):

```
 element.get(0).setAttribute("viewBox", value);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't work. I've tried with different names to be sure. element.attr sets lowercase attributes names everytime.

Comment: You made me find that jQuery was the reason, and thanks for pointing out directives. It seems very powerful.

Comment: Very annoying! element.get(0).setAttribute("viewBox", value); instead of element.attr('viewBox', value) works with angular 1.4.7

Answer (score 12):

Looking for a solution myself I came upon this answer the correct way to achieve this is by using pattern transform `ng-attr-view_box`

Comment: This should be the verified answer. Works beautifully.

Comment: doesn't work with angular 1.2 + jquery 1.9.  You must have at least jquery 3.0 for this to work properly.

Comment: This is the official solution from AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution didn't work. I'm no javascript pro but this did.

```
app.directive('vbox', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('vbox', function (value) {
                element.context.setAttribute('viewBox', value);
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi, you got to read the full answer. It works, used the same solution as you give ( but with ̉element.get(0) )

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in a directive linking function (imagine a scope with the variables used):

```
        var svg = $compile(
            $interpolate('<svg width="{{w}}" height="{{h}}" class="vis-sample" id="vis-sample-{{$id}}" viewBox="0 0 {{w}} {{h}}" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></svg>')( scope )
        )( scope );
```

The key is using `$interpolate` before `$compile`. There has to be a better solution but this is the most direct option I know of for single-pass templates where the variables are all available initially.