# The "ng-attr" directive causes problems in SVG due case-sensitive attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I try to create a svg dynamically using angular.

Using "ng-attr" establish the properties of each svg element.

But there is a problem, some properties (like viewBox) are compiled in lowercase. (ng-attr-viewBox becomes viewbox).

"viewbox" does not work as expected.

The problem seems to be that SVG is case sensitive and Angularjs is not.

Any idea how to solve this problem.

[SAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/wk3TYW?p=preview)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" ng-attr-viewBox="{{viewBox}}"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
    <rect x="-10" y="-10" ng-attr-width="{{width}}"
      ng-attr-height="{{height}}"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CODE

```
var mod = angular.module("test1", []);


mod.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.title = "demo";

  $scope.width = 100;
  $scope.height = 100;

  var update = function() {
    $scope.viewBox = "-50 -50 " + $scope.width + " " + $scope.height;
  }

  $scope.$watch('width', update);
  $scope.$watch('height', update);


}]);
```

Comment: why not just do `<svg version="1.1" viewBox="{{viewBox}}">` ? or Use a directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594497/how-to-prevent-angularjs-to-lowercase-html-attributes

Comment: Thank you. search for answer but not found it. flaged duplicated