# Angular with SVG graphics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I am very new to Angular js. And i can not understand why Angular can not properly work with `<svg>`.
When i try to make SVG elements active with angular, i see errors in console:
For example in directive i have following template:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='svgtime'>\
  <path stroke='#fff' stroke-width='5' d='M {{radius+line_size}} 2.50000119262981 A    {{radius+line_size-2.5}} {{radius+line_size-2.5}} 0 1 1 {{radius+line_size-0.1}} 2.500055466403296 Z' fill='transparent'></path>
  <path fill='transparent' stroke='#9BC7F2' stroke-width='2' ng-attr-d='M 60 2  A  58 58 0 0 1 77.83716831288882 5.497827994417321'></path>
```

I also set `radius` variables in scope of directive, but this code does not works. Console indicates that i have invalide value for `d` attribute of path element. I also tryed `ng-attr-d` as suggested in official doc for Angular directives, but it does not worked too? Why this happens. What is so special in SVG elements. I think it is connected with how Angular replaces {{}} to actual values. May be {{value}} is replaced with Angular by calling `$interpolate` after `<svg>` is rendered and i get error?
Also i know about tricks like: [How to prevent AngularJS from making lowercase HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594497/how-to-prevent-angularjs-to-lowercase-html-attributes) But why `ng-attr-*` does not works?

Comment: Can you show us the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

So i concluded that `SVG` attributes can not be used with data-bindings. Instead you can make your own directive for custom attribute. Changing custom attribute you can change target attribute in `SVG`. For example,

```
tester.directive("svgD", function() {
return {
    scope : {
        "svgD" : '@'
    },

    link: function(scope,element, attr) {
            attr.$observe("svgD",function() {
               attr.$set("d",scope.svgD );
            });
    }

}
```

});

The solution is the same as for [How to prevent AngularJS from making lowercase HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594497/how-to-prevent-angularjs-to-lowercase-html-attributes). The question is why this happens with `SVG`.