# why does setAttribute work when jQuery's attr doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, attr, setattribute

I'm trying to dynamically rotate a gradient in an SVG based on mouse position and it's all working fine except this one line. The trouble is I can't seem to get the jQuery `attr` method to work. `setAttribute` works fine to replace `rotate(#,#,#)` inside of the attribute `gradientTransform` but `attr` doesn't. The part that I'm really having trouble with is that I can change other attributes with `attr` (as in the third example in the fiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/samt/8yUNL/

this one works

```
mainLogoFill[0].setAttribute('gradientTransform', 'rotate(45,100,100)');
```

this one doesn't

```
mainLogoFill.attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90,100,100)');
```

this one throws me.. why does it work?

```
mainLogoFill.attr('x1', '100');
```

Comment: @jfriend00 nope! prop() method also doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the attr() in jQuery force lowercase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361971/does-the-attr-in-jquery-force-lowercase)

Comment: SVG is based on XML, so [*attribute names are case sensitive*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#CaseSensitivity).

Comment: @RobG Yeah, jQuery tries to detect whether it's in XML mode, but does a suboptimal job at it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery uses toLowerCase with attribute names, so it ends up as `gradienttransform` not `gradientTransform`, which is a new attribute and not the same as the one you already have, hence the issues.

The `attr()` method starts like this

```
function (elem, name, value) {
    var hooks, ret, nType = elem.nodeType;

    // don't get/set attributes on text, comment and attribute nodes
    if (!elem || nType === 3 || nType === 8 || nType === 2) {
        return;
    }

    // Fallback to prop when attributes are not supported
    if (typeof elem.getAttribute === core_strundefined) {
        return jQuery.prop(elem, name, value);
    }

    // All attributes are lowercase
    // Grab necessary hook if one is defined
    if (nType !== 1 || !jQuery.isXMLDoc(elem)) {
        name = name.toLowerCase(); // this is the line where the name is lowercased
        hooks = jQuery.attrHooks[name] || (jQuery.expr.match.bool.test(name) ? boolHook : nodeHook);
    }

    if (value !== undefined) {
```

The way around this is to use setAttribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although SVG is based on XML (and thus uses case sensitive attribute names), jQuery's detection fails at this point and transforms attribute names to lower case.

If you don't like using `.setAttribute()` everywhere, an alternative is to patch jQuery by overriding how it determines XML mode:

```
jQuery.isXMLDoc = function(elem)
{
    return (elem.ownerDocument || elem).documentElement.nodeName !== "HTML" || 
        (elem.namespaceURI).indexOf('html') == -1;
}
```

The above code additionally checks if the namespace of the current element has the term `"html"` in it; the namespace for SVG is `"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, so jQuery will not alter the case of your property names.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/samt/8yUNL/)

Comment: Though that is really an "isHTMLDoc" method. ;-) Don't get too cocky though, IE thinks a plain HTML document is XHTML (http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml), which is case sensitive and requires HTML attribute tag and names in lower case, yet returns values for HTML tag names in upper case. C'est la vie. :-/

Comment: @RobG Isn't it more like an "is not html doc" method? :)

Comment: —err, yes. I was thinking it *needs* an isHTMLDoc method, but that's not what came out. :-(