# Setting viewBox attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an `<svg>` element on my page and would like to give it a [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute. When I try this with jQuery, like so:

```
$('svg').attr('viewBox', '0 0 800 400');
```

It *almost* works, but it gives the element a "view**b**ox" attribute (notice the lower case 'b'). This attribute requires the camel case to work, at least in Chrome where I have tested it. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Have you checked out this? I think it's what you're after
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361971/does-the-attr-in-jquery-force-lowercase

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved this using @Mat's native Javascript `setAttribute` tip,

```
$('svg').removeAttr('viewBox');
$('svg').each(function () { $(this)[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 800 400') });
```