# Camel case in HTML tag attributes and jquery - doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Yes, there are similar questions, but they are about jquery adding lowercase attributes like here: [Does the attr() in jQuery force lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361971/does-the-attr-in-jquery-force-lowercase)

But I have a different situation. Here is my HTML5 piece of code:

```
<tr class='projectRow' data-projectId='34'>
```

Notice that this is camelCase. And now this code does not work:

```
//"this" points to a child element
$id = $(this).closest('.projectRow').data('projectId');//undefined
```

But if I make it lowercase:

```
$(this).closest('.projectRow').data('projectid');
```

It works.

When I look at the source code, it's clearly "projectId" (camelCase), but when in chrome -> dev tools -> elements then it's "projectid" (lowercase) o_O

No wonder jquery can't get this value, but why is Chrome doing this? I did  something similar hundreds of times before, although was using a - like in "project-id" and now after so many years of making web applications I discover something like this o_O

Comment: `data` attributes (along with all attributes names in term of best practices) should be lower case, otherwise it interferes with the way jQuery stores them in it's cache.

Comment: OK, but why Chrome is doing this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you're interested, it's not only problem with jquery, actually I'm breaking spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: thanks, I knew jQuery didn't like mixed-case data attributes but didn't realise they were in the spec as being lower case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

The [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity) states attribute names are case-insensitive, meaning writing them all as uppercase is as good as writing them all in lowercase or in camelCase:

> Attribute names for HTML elements may be written with any mix of lowercase and uppercase letters that are a case-insensitive match for
>   the names of the attributes given in the HTML elements section of this
>   document; that is, attribute names are case-insensitive.

**EDIT #2**

[Another part of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) states it more explicitly:

> All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get
>   ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase
>   letters doesn't affect such documents.

**Original Answer**

jQuery specifies that if you want to access attributes via camelCase, then hyphenate them such that:

`data-project-id="1"` is accessed via `$(element).data('projectId');`

Comment: OK, I'll be simply using lowercase, but why is Chrome doing this? Is this in a HTML5 specification, that attributes must be lowercase? I can't find it.

Comment: so... it means Chrome should **not** make them lowercase... right?

Comment: OK, nevermind, my understanding was that since HTML doesn't care about case Chrome should not "repair" it in any way, while it's the opposite.

Comment: Adam: actually I'm breaking spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: SO has broken my link, if anybody's interested then it's point #3.2.5.9  BTW - it's a bug in SO imho, asterixes **are** allowed in URL and SO cuts a URL on this character. Is there a place one can file a bug related to SO?

Comment: Using `data-project-id` as attribute name and accessing it as `data('projectId')` might be seen as a violation of the principle of least astonishment (if the reader is looking for `project-id` in the JS code)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ".data()" you could just use ".attr()" to access the value of the attribute, then you could reference it by the name you've given it; like the following:

```
$(element).attr('data-projectId');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with ordinary Javascript and use HTML5 this should work:

```
element.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-projectId')
```