# setAttribute makes the attribute name lowercase

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, dom

I create elements with the `var l = document.createElement("label");` and I assign its attributes with `l.setAttribute("formControlName","e");`. 
The problem is that the setAttribute method puts the formControlName in lowercase letters as you can see in the image below. I work with ionic so the capital letters are needed. Does anyone see what I did wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camel case in HTML tag attributes and jquery - doesn't work, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176474/camel-case-in-html-tag-attributes-and-jquery-doesnt-work-why)

Comment: Do you have a reference for "ionic so the capital letters are needed"? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: This is rather a requirement of Angular which is a framework below Ionic.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
l.setAttributeNS(null, "formControlName","e");
```

'setAttributeNS()' doesn't convert the name to lower case.