# How can I add a camelcase attribute to a dom element via an Angular 6 directive?

Tags: javascript, angular

It seems impossible. Whether I use `@HostBinding` or `elementRef.nativeElement.setAttibute(camelCaseAttribute, "true")` in both cases the **camelCaseAttribute** becomes **camelcaseattribute** in the rendered dom.

All I want to do is set **ngDraggable** using a directive, why is that not possible? (**ngdraggable** will not work)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setAttribute makes the attribute name lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300610/setattribute-makes-the-attribute-name-lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes are not case sensitive. So it doesn't matter.

> Attribute names for HTML elements may be written with any mix of lowercase and uppercase letters that are a case-insensitive match for the names of the attributes given in the HTML elements section of this document; that is, attribute names are case-insensitive.

source: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html

If you are trying to add `ngDraggable` directive conditionally I think this is not a good approach. Imho you should ask another question how to apply `ngDraggable` dynamically.