# Custom attribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a custom attribute to add a title to each links.

```
<a href="#" nameOf="The Flower" id="ex1"></a>
<a href="#" nameOf="The Tree" id="ex2"></a>
```

And here is the jQuery code

```
$('#ex1,#ex2').append('<span class="title">'+$(this).attr("nameOf")+'</span>');
```

But the link displays as **undefined**. How can I fix this.

Comment: Custom attributes were used in the past, but since HTML5 with the support for the global `data-*` attributes, it is strongly recommended to use the `data-*` attributes instead. It is also recommended to use all small-letters for HTML tags and attributes. So change it to `data-nameof`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `this` in your example is window, it does not know that it is supposed to be a reference to a link. In order to use this, you would need to use a function inside of append() and return the string.

```js
$('#ex1,#ex2').append( function() { return '<span class="title">'+$(this).attr("nameOf")+'</span>'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" nameOf="The Flower" id="ex1"></a>
<a href="#" nameOf="The Tree" id="ex2"></a>
```

And if you do not want to use JavaScript at all and have the text show up in the link, there is always a CSS Solution.

```css
a[nameOf]::before {
  content: attr(nameOf)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" nameOf="The Flower" id="ex1"></a>
<a href="#" nameOf="The Tree" id="ex2"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the element tags & append to it

```js
$('a').each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).append('<span class="title">' + $(this).attr("nameOf") + '</span>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" nameOf="The Flower" id="ex1"></a>
<a href="#" nameOf="The Tree" id="ex2"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same as below using loop:

```
$('[nameOf]').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<span class="title">' + $(this).attr("nameOf") + '</span>')
});
```

but as per [w3c](https://validator.w3.org/about.html) rules you can not use `nameOf` attribute in `a` tag, So you can use use `data-nameof` instead.

Answer (score 0):

in HTML you can't create a custom attribute in camel case. if you want to add more words to your custom attr, you need to add a `-` symbol. so, for your case, do.

```
<a href="#" name-of="The Flower" id="ex1"></a>
```

later, for a search, I suggest you use the camel case.

```
$(element).attr('nameOf');
```

Comment: more info [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176474/camel-case-in-html-tag-attributes-and-jquery-doesnt-work-why)