# I want show title in circle tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have a `circle` tag HTML5.

When i add a tag `title` and hover it, it show `title`.

But, i add tag `title` by jquery, it not show `title`.

This is my code :

```
 <circle class="visible" style="fill: blue" cx="900" cy="350" r="6">
     <!--<title>DeviceB|2015/09/01 24:27</title> ( When i add title by jquery and it show title)--> 
</circle>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('circle').click(function (e) {
                $(this).append('<title>DeviceB|2015/09/01 24:27</title>');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can create a jsfiddle for this. A suggestion can be to use class 'visible' instead of 'this' before append.

Comment: Your question is unclear. A circle element -- are you intending to use SVG?

Answer (score 0):

The `<title>` tag is meant for usage in `<head>` to show the title of the webpage in the browser tab in modern browsers and in window frame in older browsers.

Otherwise, the attribute `title=""` is used in the main document for a tooltip of the description of the hovered element.

Try adding other elements instead, like: `<h1>`, `<span>` for a semantic webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception in your code. A structural document title (you more likely want that rather than a bouncing or changing title) is set with a `<title>` tag inside a `<head>` tag. The user won't expect the document title to change after it's fully loaded.

However, if you really want to change the title at runtime, you may access it with `document.title`. Also, you should save your device name somewhere easy to control. For example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="device_name" value="DeviceB-FooBar-Barbarian-Etc" />
```

Then :

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('circle').click(function(e) {
      document.title = $('#device-name').val();
   });
});
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The title tag is allowed inside svg elements and acts as a tooltip on mouseover ([TITLE — the SVG accessible name element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title)

My understanding is the svg title must be created in an svg namespace for it to work properly (and keep it separate from the HTML tag of the same name).  For completeness sake, I've included working code for both JQuery and JavaScript.

Also helpful [What is jQuery for Document.createElementNS()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572304/what-is-jquery-for-document-createelementns)

```js
//Assign svg namespace - required
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

//Click the blue circle, then mouseover for the <TITLE>/tooltip
//JQuery version
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#c2').click(function() {
    //Create the new title element
    t = $(document.createElementNS(svgns, 'title'));
    //Assign a value to the text between the title tags
    $(t).html("TITLE (i.e. svg tooltip) created by JQuery");
    //Append it as a child of the svg circle which was clicked
    $(this).append(t);
  });
});

//Plain JavaScript version
//Click the red circle, then mouseover for the  <TITLE>/tooltip
function addTitle(el) {
  //Create the new title element
  t = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'title');
  //Assign a value to the text between the title tags
  t.innerHTML = 'TITLE (i.e. svg tooltip) created by JS';
  //Append it as a child of the svg circle which was clicked
  el.appendChild(t);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<circle id="c1" style="fill: red"  cx="25" cy="25" r="20" onclick="addTitle(this);"/>
<circle id="c2" style="fill: blue" cx="75" cy="25" r="20" />
</svg>
<br /> Click red circle, then mouseover for title created by JS<br /> Click blue circle, then mouseover for title created by JQuery<br />
```